# R edit file, how to suppress R [1] and quotes in output

Tags: r

I'm doing very simple thing (I thought) and having this line # brackets and double quotes in my output file, how to suppress this? My goal just replace string in file, and either to edit it or create new file.

```
d <- readLines("C:\\R\\MX1_vx.txt")
d
d1 <-   paste(substr(d,1,15),"  00000")
d1
sink('out_v5.txt')
d1
sink()
```

and this my console output.

```
> d
[1] "01 Alpha   1400101211101100110011101111111100 1"
[2] "02 Bravo   2500101211101100110011101111111100 2"
[3] "03 Charlie 3600101211101100110011101111111100 3"
```

In out_v5 file I see those chars, I actually that, there only 2 lines.

```
[1] "01 Alpha   1400   00000" "02 Bravo   2500   00000"
[3] "03 Charlie 3600   00000"
```

Comment: What is `z` in your line `d1 <-   paste(substr(z,1,15),"  00000")`?

Comment: I don't see how the output file can contain different data if d1 is the same in each case. I suspect all relevant code is not shown.

Comment: Sorry Adam , was typO, replaced z for d. and still have those [1]..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using write() instead of sink() , I get the output without [1] and "s like this :

01 Alpha   1400   00000

02 Bravo   2500   00000

03 Charlie 3600   00000

```
    d <- readLines("C:\\R\\MX1_vx.txt")
    d1 <-   paste(substr(d,1,15),"  00000")
    write(d1, "out.txt")
```